# How can I combine model parameter uncertainty and input uncertainty?

Tags: bootstrap, nonlinear-regression, uncertainty, multivariate-regression, error-propagation

Suppose I have a finite data sample $\mathbf{S} = \{ (\mathbf{x}^{(1)}, \mathbf{y}^{(1)}), \dots, (\mathbf{x}^{(N)}, \mathbf{y}^{(N)}) \}$ from an unknown data-generating function of the form

$$ \mathbf{y} = f(\mathbf{x}), \quad \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^m $$

I will attempt a non-linear regression:

$$ \hat{\mathbf{w}} = \underset{\mathbf{w}}{\rm arg \ min} \ \ell (\mathbf{y} - \hat{f}(\mathbf{x}; \mathbf{w}))$$

where $\mathbf{w}$ are the parameters of my regression function, and $\ell$ is some standard loss function.

As a conseqence of local (rather than global) optimisation, and potential model misspecification, I expect that if I repeat this regression on bootstrapped samples of $\mathbf{S}$, I will observe a sampling distribution for $\hat{\mathbf{w}}$, and the resulting prediction $f(\mathbf{x}^{(N+1)}; \hat{\mathbf{w}})$ for $\mathbf{x}^{(N+1)}$.

To quantify the resulting uncertainty in my prediction, I could make a bootstrap estimate of the variance

$$ \mathbf{s}^2_\text{boot} = E [ ( \hat{f}(\mathbf{x}^{(N+1)}; \hat{\mathbf{w}}) - E [ \hat{f}(\mathbf{x}^{(N+1)}; \hat{\mathbf{w}}) ] )^2 ] $$

Now assume that there is some uncertainty in the input $\mathbf{x}^{(N+1)}$.

I believe the simplest way to account for this is to assume a linear approximation (first-order Taylor expansion) for $\hat{f}$, and propagate the uncertainty via

$$\mathbf{K}_{\mathbf{yy}} = \nabla E[\hat{f}(\mathbf{x}^{(N+1)}; \hat{\mathbf{w})}]^\top \mathbf{K}_{\mathbf{xx}}  \nabla E[\hat{f}(\mathbf{x}^{(N+1)}; \hat{\mathbf{w})}]$$

where $\nabla E[\hat{f}(\mathbf{x}^{(N+1)}; \hat{\mathbf{w})}]$ is the Jacobian of the bootstrap estimator, and $\mathbf{K}$ are the covariance matrices of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$, respectively.

Then the variance as a result of the input uncertainty is

$$ \mathbf{s}^2_\text{lin} = \mathrm{tr} (\mathbf{K}_{\mathbf{yy}}) $$

How can I combine these two sources of uncertainty? Can I sum the variances as:

$$ \mathbf{s}_\text{tot}^2 = \mathbf{s}_\text{boot}^2 + \mathbf{s}_\text{lin}^2 $$